# How to Access Parent Window's Control from user control window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have one parent control named parent.xaml. In that i have put some controls like Grid, Popup etc.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">POC For GOTO in WPF Grid</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>-</TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Click="btn1_Click">Click To Use GOTO</Button>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <DataGrid x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding _CommonClass}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Time}" Header="Time" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" Header="id" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Program}" Header="Program" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Duration}" Header="Duration" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Description}" Header="Description" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>

            <Popup Name="Popup1" Width="240" Height="auto" Placement="Center" PlacementRectangle="50,50,50,100">
                <Border BorderBrush="DarkCyan" BorderThickness="3">
                    <local:GoToUC x:Name="myUserControlInstance"/>
                </Border>
            </Popup>

    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I have one user control named child.xaml.

```
<StackPanel Background="AliceBlue" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="200">
    <Grid Margin="20,20,20,20">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="tb_time" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0"></TextBox>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">-</TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="btn_goto" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Click="btn_goto_Click" Width="90">GOTO</Button>
        <Button x:Name="btn_cancel" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Click="btn_cancel_Click" Width="50">Close</Button>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Now from `child.xaml` i need to do some operation on parent window's controls.Like i want to close parent popup from child window.
I have used this method:

```
Window _parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

But I am not sure how to access controls out of `_parentwindow` object.

Comment: post that as answer, and mark it accepted. That will make it easier for people with same question to find the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer finally

`Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);

object obj= parentWindow.FindName("Popup1"); 
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup pop = (System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup)obj;

pop.IsOpen = false;`

Answer (score 0):

```
this.ParentForm.Close() // is a good way to close the parentform from the user control.
```